# How can I inject run-time parameters along with a volatile dependency into a constructor with Castle Windsor?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

Some of my classes have a constructor similar to the following:

```
public class MyComponent : BaseComponent, IMyComponent
{
    public MyComponent(IPostRepository postsRepo, int postId, ICollection<string> fileNames)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

`IPostRepository` is a volatile dependency, but it can be initialized at application start. The postId and fileNames arguments are only known at run time.

**How can I use Castle Windsor (3.2.0, if it matters) to handle the injection of the `IPostRepository` dependency while still allowing run-time constructor parameters?**

(While one approach might be to refactor `MyComponent`, this would be a significant undertaking as many other portions of the code already refer to `MyComponent`.)

**Here's where I've gotten so far**: I think that I need to create a `MyComponentFactory`. The interface of `MyComponentFactory` would look like

```
public interface IMyComponentFactory
{
    IMyComponent Create(params object[] args);
}
```

This `IMyComponentFactory` would be injected into the layer above (the controller in my case) like so:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private IMyComponentFactory _myComponentFactory;

    public MyController(IMyComponentFactory myComponentFactory)
    {
        _myComponentFactory = myComponentFactory;
    }

    public ActionResult MyAction(int postId)
    {
        List<string> fileNames = new List<string>();
        // ...

        // Creates a new instance of the resolved IMyComponent with the IPostRepository that was injected into IMyComponentFactory and the run time parameters.
        IMyComponent myComponent = _myComponentFactory.Create(postId, fileNames); 

        // Now do stuff with myComponent

        return View();
    }
}
```

Finally, I have attempted to let Castle Windsor create the factory implementation by registering my `IMyComponentFactory` in the composition root like so:

```
// Add Factory facility
container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();

container.Register(Component.For<IMyComponentFactory>().AsFactory());
```

Doing this results in a `DependencyResolverException` with a message of

> Could not resolve non-optional dependency for
>   'Playground.Examples.Components.MyComponent'
>   (Playground.Examples.Components.MyComponent). Parameter 'postId' type
>   'System.Int32'

The error makes sense, and I'm guessing that I need to create a custom implementation of `IMyComponentFactory`, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you do something like the following:

```
public class MyComponentFactory : IMyComponentFactory
{
    private IPostRepository postRepository;

    public MyComponentFactory(IPostRepository postRepository)
    {
       this.postRepository = postRepository;
    }

    public IMyComponent Create(int postId, ICollection<string> fileNames)
    {            
        return new MyComponent(this.postRepository, postId, fileNames);
    }
}
```

I would use explicit parameters in your `Create` method.

Then register `MyComponentFactory` against the interface `IMyComponentFactory` (as a singleton)

Comment: Ah, that's similar to what I had before I started moving toward using a DI container (Castle Windsor). Can I avoid the concrete reference to `MyComponent` in your answer? It seems like it is violating the open/closed principle, similar to the first solution in this [blog post](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/15/ImplementinganAbstractFactory/). Ideally, It seems like I should go with something similar to the second or third solutions in that post, but as they don't accept run time parameters. I also wasn't able to figure out how to register the second one in Windsor.

Comment: Well the open/closed principle doesn't really apply here because we're creating a factory type specifically to create instances of 'MyComponent', after all it's called a 'MyComponentFactory', so we wouldn't want it extensible to support the creation of other types. It's not quite as nice as the container automatically generating a type that returns the implementation currently registered against IMyComponent, but that does add a dependency on the container you're using (i.e. Castle Windsor).

Comment: In other words, if you replace Castle Windsor with a container that doesn't support generation of factory types or one that requires a differently shaped abstraction, then you're back to implementing a factory type per concrete implementation of your component or service.

Comment: Those are good points. I suppose that I also wouldn't want to make my controller dependent on Castle Windsor. Would it be possible to inject the type to my factory? Then, one could use System.Activator to create an instance of that type.

Comment: Well your controller doesn't have any dependency on Castle Windsor because it doesn't have any reference to the container. I don't see any value in passing a type to the factory because the factory has to be resolved via the container so it couldn't resolve the Type parameter and then you'd have the issue of not being able to create the instance of the component unless it had a parameterless constructor, and it also wouldn't perform as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare strongly typed parameters of `Create` factory method:

```
public interface IMyComponentFactory
{
    IMyComponent Create(int postId, ICollection<string> fileNames);
}
```

And don't forget to register your component:

```
Component.For<IMyComponent>().ImplementedBy<MyComponent>().LifestyleTransitional()
```